# Not able to send invoice to the donors email?

Tags: apex, trigger, singleemailmessage

I have a below apex class and trigger for sending invoices to donors. But in sandbox, it's working fine but in production, I am getting the below error.

> SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, the Email address is invalid: null: [toAddresses, null]

Any one can you suggest where I have to do the fixes.?

**Apex Class**

```java
public class SendInvoice {
    public id oppId{get;set;}   
    @Future(callout=true)
    public static void invoiceGenerate(Id oppId,String emailToSend, String donorsName){
        
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();     
        PageReference invoice = Page.DonationAttachment;
        invoice.getParameters().put('id',oppId);
        
        //Blob b = invoice.getContent();
        Blob b = !Test.isRunningTest() ? invoice.getContent() : Blob.valueOf('test');        
        attachment.setBody(b);
        attachment.setInline(true);
        attachment.setContentType('application/pdf');
        attachment.setFileName('Donation Invoice.pdf');
        //pdfBody = pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();
        
        string[] toAddress = new string[]{emailToSend};
            //String[] toAddresses = new String[] { theUser.Email };
            
            if(emailToSend == null) {
                toAddress.add('helen.spca@gmail.com');
            }
        system.debug('@nu----------------------emailTo----------'+emailToSend);
        //string[] toAddress = new string[]{'shahi@telcowin.com','Tanisha@telcowin.com'};
        string[] Nameof = new string[]{donorsName};
            system.debug('@nu----------------------donorsName----------'+donorsName); 
        email.setSenderDisplayName('SPCA Admin');    
        email.setToAddresses(toAddress);
        email.setHtmlBody('Dear   ' +  donorsName +',<br/>'+
                          'Thank you for your kind donations!<br/><br/>'+
                          '<br/>We truly appreciate your support for SPCA Selangor.<br/><br/>'+
                          'Without your support we would be unable to help these voiceless Paws.<br/><br/>'+
                          'Your transaction has been completed, and a receipt for your tax deductible donation has been emailed to you.<br/><br/>'+
                          '"No act of kindness, no matter how small, is ever wasted."-Aesop<br/><br/>'+
                          'Thank you again for your gracious support.<br/><br/><br/>'+
                          'Regards,<br/>'+
                          'SPCA selangor'); 
        email.setSubject('Thanks Note for Contibutions');
        email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{attachment});
        
        Messaging.SendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});         
        
        
    }
}
```

**Apex Trigger**

```java
trigger DonationCloseTrigger on Opportunity (before insert,after Update,before update) {
    //Populate the Account Related fields
    
    if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter){
        Set<id> oppCloseId = new Set<Id>();
        List<id> accIds = new List<id>();
        String emailToSend;
        string donorsName;
        for(Opportunity opp:trigger.new)
        {
            Opportunity opptyPrior = Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.ID);
            if(opp.stageName == 'Posted' && opp.stageName!=opptyPrior.stageName)
            {
                oppCloseId.add(opp.id);
            }
            System.debug('inLoop'+oppCloseId);
        }
        
        List<Opportunity> oppsToFetchAccs = [select id,Email_Address__c,accountId from Opportunity where id in:oppCloseId];
        for(Opportunity oppty :oppsToFetchAccs)
        {
            accIds.add(oppty.accountId);
        }
        
        Account [] acc = [select Id, Name, Email__c from Account Where Id in:accIds];
        //Contact[] con = [select Id, Name, Email from contact where accountid in:accIds];
        if(acc.size()>0){
            emailToSend = acc[0].Email__c;
            donorsName = acc[0].Name;
        }
        for(Opportunity opp:oppsToFetchAccs)
        {
            SendInvoice.invoiceGenerate(opp.Id,emailToSend,donorsName);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reason for this.

1. Check if this custom field Email__c is not blank.
2. Check if Email__c has right field level access granted.